# Transfer of ERC-20 tokens fails, even though smart contract has enough token balance

Tags: tokens, erc-20, transfer

I am trying to develop a buy function for my token smart contract, but it fails on the transfer:

```
transfer(msg.sender, amountToBuy);
```

It fails with the Error: `'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance'`, even though the contract has enough tokens in its balance:
[image: Enough Tokens in balance, 400k to be exact.]

Comment: Can you give more details? Is the contract sending the tokens the ERC20 contract? Can you supply a sample code that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the Answer. Instead of just doing transfer in the code, I create an object out of the IERC20 Interface.

This is needed for a smart contract to transfer its own tokens:

```
IERC20(this).transfer(msg.sender, amountToBuy);
```